# How to disable WebFrameView pageDown scroll when spacebar key is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I am building an HTML editor with live preview (objective-C, Mac OS X) in a WebView. So far so good and got almost all features I need: both views (NSTextView and WebView) scrolls in sync, preview is rendered perfectly. My one problem is with WebView's default reaction to space bar key: scroll down. I've spent many hours digging in WebKit sources, trying to disable it without a success. I was trying to subclass WebView and catch keyDown there, swizzle keyDown for WebFrameView, refuse firstRsponder status... without much luck. What I am missing here? Any idea how to get rid of this behaviour would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried subclassing `NSScrollView` and capturing space at there?

Comment: There's no problem with catching space key, when the WebView has focus, but in my case focus is on NSTextView and WebView is getting the event from ...? Subclassing NSScrollView can't help. How to stop NSTextView from passing key event to the responder chain (but still have space key working)?

Answer (score 2):

Same here. As an experiment, I intercepted all the key events using `NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`, mapping every space to underscore: I got underscores instead of spaces in the NSTextView, but the WebView kept scrolling down. I guess that WebView is intercepting keyboard events at a different level.

However, I noticed that the scroll-down issue happens only when the application updates the WebView content while processing – more or less at the same time – the user input.

Hence I inserted a delay – updating the WebView content only after a certain interval of user inactivity – e.g.:

```
private var _refreshAskCount = 0
func refreshWebViewIfIdontAskYouAgainInTheNext(#seconds: Double) {
    let count = ++self._refreshAskCount
    let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if count == self._refreshAskCount {
            self.renderWebView()
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to solve the issue, or at least to greatly reduce it.